# Asking menu that a brand of shop serve?

Tags: grammatical-number, proper-nouns

Sorry if it is confusing.

> What does a Starbuck serve?

or

> What do Starbucks serve?

The second one makes sense for me, since there are many Starbuck shops, but I'm still uncertain.

Which one should be grammatically correct?

Comment: Then, what if I change "Starbuck" to "coffee shop", which one should correct?

Comment: The restaurant is technically named "Starbucks"... so excluding the "s" even when singular would be incorrect.

Comment: What does a coffee shop serve? What do coffee shops serve?

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, which one?

Comment: Either one is fine.

Comment: Is this question about American English, British English, both, or neither?

Comment: We should probably edit this question to use a company name that doesn't end in "s".  Using "Starbucks" is raising other issues that the question isn't really about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the company is *Starbucks* -- it is never written without the 's', whether you are speaking of the singular company, a single shop, or multiple shops.

If you are speaking of a single shop, use a singular verb:

> What **does** the Starbucks on the corner serve?

If you are speaking of multiple shops, use a plural verb:

> What **do** the Starbucks in Minneapolis serve that other Starbucks **don't** serve?

If you are speaking of the company, AmE use calls for a singular verb:

> What **does** Starbucks permit its stores to serve?

Comment: What sorts of things are served in a Starbucks?

Comment: @Catija A graceful and ingenious way of sidestepping the issue!

Comment: Actually, I was so focused on the lack of "s" on Starbuck**s** that I didn't even think that the center of the question was do vs does

Answer (score 5):

I would actually just say `What does Starbucks serve?`

I think this, because Starbucks is a singular noun. Starbucks is a chain of stores. I think typically it is unnecessary to ask about one particular store, because a chain of stores all serve the same thing (almost).

I would think if someone asked about just one store that they were asking what that store serves that is different from all the other stores.

Comment: I agree; say it the same way as we would if the company name did not have an 's' at the end: _What does Burger King serve?_